# Allow Multiple inputs in java calculator

Tags: java, parsing

I'm working on a small calculator in Eclipse, where the user inputs an equation like `1 + 1`. However, I'm not sure about how to allow the user to input more complicated equations like `1 + 2 * 3 / 4`.

Also, if the user tries to input a string which is not a valid equation, I want an error to appear. Here's my code:

```
public static double addition(double x, double y) // The Addition Operation
{
    double add = x + y;
    return add;
}

public static double subtraction(double x, double y) // The Subtraction Operation
{
    double sub = x - y;
    return sub;
}

public static double division(double x, double y) // The Devision Operation
{
    double div = x / y;
    return div;
}

public static double multiplication(double x, double y) // The Multiplication Operation
{
    double multi = x * y;
    return multi;
}

public static double factorial(double x) // The Factorial (F!)
{ 
    double result = 1;
    while (x > 1)
    {
        result = result * x;
        x = x - 1;
    }
    return result;
}

static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // a Global Scanner.

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double numb1, numb2;
    char operation;
    System.out.println("Enter Your Equation: ");

    // Split string by space
    String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split("");

    // Convert to corresponding types
    operation = parts[1].charAt(0);

    switch (operation)
    {
        case '+':
            numb1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            operation = parts[1].charAt(0);
            numb2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            System.out.println("The Product is: " + addition(numb1, numb2));
            break;

        case '-':
            numb1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            operation = parts[1].charAt(0);
            numb2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            System.out.println("The Product is: " + subtraction(numb1, numb2));
            break;
        case '*':
            numb1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            operation = parts[1].charAt(0);
            numb2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            System.out.println("The Product is: " + multiplication(numb1, numb2));
            break;
        case '/':
            numb1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            operation = parts[1].charAt(0);
            numb2 = Integer.parseInt(parts[2]);
            System.out.println("The Product is: " + division(numb1, numb2));
            break;
        case '!':
            numb1 = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
            operation = parts[1].charAt(0);
            System.out.println("The Product is: " + factorial(numb1));
    }
}
```

Comment: i suggest to use some regex rules for split big String to many numbers with Operators..   
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/236807-regex-use-for-a-simple-calculator-app/
   this might help to you

Comment: <offtopic>The comment `//The Addition Operation` for the method `addition` is completely unnecesary </offtopic>

Comment: @l19 but... but how would you know what it does otherwise?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The question you are asking is too broad.  I expect this is homework, and you are supposed to solve the problem yourself instead of getting somebody else to write it for you.  Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask] for details.  Start by searching for "parse arithmetic expression" on Google.

Comment: @HackerGK: how would you implement operator precedence using regular expressions? I think the OP needs a parser.

Comment: :) after extracting operators, we can create some function to process them easily :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some easy ways to evaluate an expression in Java already, but assuming this is for learning purposes:

The trickiest part of parsing a math equation is accounting for the order of operations—that is, you can't just iterate through the equation and compute it bit by bit (Something like `3 + 2 * 5` would fail in this case).

What you're looking for is a way to *parse infix expressions*; the section [here](http://www.smccd.net/accounts/hasson/C++2Notes/ArithmeticParsing.html) about that very subject walks you through the basic idea of what you have to do. There's no Java code there, but that would take the fun out of it, right?